# deplyoing php + Node js app on google cloud server

Tags: php, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am developing an application on codeigniter(PHP) and I have deployed it on Google Cloud, some part of this runs on NodeJS. How can I deploy it on Google Cloud server as my app consist of both PHP+NodeJS code?

Here is my `app.yaml` file. What should the runtime be?

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:


- url: /assets/css
  static_dir: assets/css

- url: /assets/img
  static_dir: assets/img

- url: /assets/js
  static_dir: assets/js


- url: /.*
  script: index.php

env_variables:

    MYSQL_USER: 'root'
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: '******'
    MYSQL_DSN: 'mysql:dbname=***;unix_socket=/cloudsql/***-1515835105404:asia-south1:truevlinstance'

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: '***-1515835105404:asia-south1:truevlinstance'
```

Comment: you need to have 2 app engines, one is for PHP and other one for NODE JS. otherwise use compute engine

Comment: okay. DO i need to deploy it again over the compute engine?

Comment: In compute engine you can setup everything as a linux machine.

Comment: I want to deploy it with app engine. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to know what the best option for you would be without looking at your application, but within App Engine you have two options.

1. [Deploy multiple services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_multiple_services). One service with PHP and the other one with NodeJS. Both parts of the application will be in GAE, only thing left is figure out the communication.
2. [Use GAE Flex Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart). If the other option is not feasible or you want something that works out of the box, try with custom runtimes. If you are using something that is not offered in GAE by default, the usual recommendation is to define your own [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and deploy it.

> Custom runtimes let you build apps that run in an environment defined by a Dockerfile. By using a Dockerfile, you can use languages and packages that are not part of the Google Cloud Platform and use the same resources and tooling that are used in the App Engine flexible environment.